# Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'PointDto'

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

I am checking equality for x1, y1 and z1 fields of `PointDto` objects (point1 and point2)

```
Eg :-
 point1 =>   PointDto: 
      {
        x1: "1.000000",
        y1: "1.0",
        z1: undefined
        pointIndex: 0,
      }
      
point2 =>   PointDto: 
      {
        x1: 1,
        y1: 1,
        z1: undefined
        pointIndex: 1,
      }   

const keys: any = {
  "x1": "x1",
  "y1": "y1",
  "z1": "z1"
}


const isEqual = (point1: PointDto, point2: PointDto) => {

  return keys.every((key :string) => (isNaN(point1[key]) ? point1[key] : +point1[key]) === point2[key]);

}
```

But I received following typescript error, Any one have idea of how to write (point1[key]) for making typescript compiler happy

Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type `PointDto`.
`No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type PointDto.ts(7053)`

Comment: pls share reproducable example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some syntax error in your code. But to prevent the below error:

`Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'PointDto'. No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'PointDto'.`

You need to tell the `ts` compiler that `key` is a key of `PointDto` (by `keyof`). So instead of

```
(key :string) => isNaN(point1[key]) ? point1[key] : +point1[key]) === point2[key]);
```

Use this one:

```
(key :string) => {var k = key as keyof PointDto; (isNaN(point1[k]) ? point1[k] : +point1[k]) === point2[k]});
```

There is one more thing: `keys` is not an array and does not have a `every` function.